# Listview Builder Navigate to page when onTab

Tags: flutter, dart

Using listview builder, I wanted to pass a string variable (userlist[index].page) to each list so that when onTap is pressed it it navigate to that page.
can someone help to fix the code?

this is the code

```
child: ListTile(
            title: Text(
              userlist[index].title,
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                alreadySaved ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
                color: alreadySaved ? Colors.blue : Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (alreadySaved) {
                    usersavedlist.remove(userlist[index]);
                  } else {
                    usersavedlist.add(userlist[index]);
                  }
                });
              },
            ), //subtitle: Text(subtitle),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => (userlist[index].page())));
            }),
```

Comment: Do you want to navigate to a different page, but want to pass parameters along with it? If so, then you need to put the name of the actual Widget there and simply pass the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a page to navigate and pass the item list as a parameter. By example:

```
class UserDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;

  //constructor 
  UserDetail(this.user);

   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // Return the widget with the user info or whatever you want
   return ...

  }
}
```

And in your navitgator you pass like this:

```
onTap: () {
     Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
               builder: (context) => UserDetail(userlist[index])));
            }),
```